# Need help with CSS for placing span on top of an input field

Tags: magento-1.9, css, html

I am trying to make input text for street address turn red if it is too long, like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v127c14p/).

For that I have created a `<span id="street1span"></span>` in the "input-box" `div` like this:

```
<li class="wide">
                <label for="street_1" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getStreet(1)) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?>" id="street_1" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                    <span id="street1span"></span>
                </div>
            </li>
```

Which does what I want.

**The problem is that I need to get this span on top of the input field and make the actual input text transparent so it looks natural.**

**Test site**

You can play around with the CSS on my test [site](http://jt-secret-site.site/magento18/customer/address/edit/)

**e-mail**: test@test.com 
**password**: test123

(only the first address field)

I don't have a lot of experience in web design and I realise that this is more of a general question and not Magento, but there is something with Magento CSS classes that interferes with what I am trying to do, I cannot figure out what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use CSS to position the span on top of the input.

I've done a very very rough example [here](https://codepen.io/BenS48/pen/vJxRjw?editors=1100), I recommend adding new classes rather than styling `input-box`, `input-text` and using an ID.

So you can see the span is on top I've given it a red background.

[image]

Code can be seen [here](https://codepen.io/BenS48/pen/vJxRjw?editors=1100).

You'll need to tweak the code as I've removed parts of the markup and adding more CSS than is required due to not having any default styling. But this should give you a good example on how to do it.

Comment: Sorry for coming back to this, but is there a way to have the span in front of the input field while still being able to type in the field?

Comment: @JurģisTomsLiepiņš Yeah sorry, you can use `pointer-events: none;` as long as you don't need IE10 support. I've updated the codepen example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply like this

```
<li class="wide">
    <label for="street_1" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box address-field"> // class added here "address-field"
        <span id="street1span" style="display:block;"></span>
        <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getStreet(1)) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?>" id="street_1" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
    </div>
</li>
```

Or with javascript like this :

```
$('#street1span').each(function() {
    $(this).insertAfter($(this).parent().find('.address-field'));
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/amir_prince/m945u17w/)

Comment: Euh why the downvote ?

Comment: I have not downvoted! will try this later and post back;)

Comment: Hmm, this just puts the span above the input box and not on top of it

Comment: above but not on top ? in order you want to display the span first then the input box ?

Comment: With "on top" I mean, literally overlapping with the input text perfectly

Comment: look my update i added this `style="display:block;`